# Trying Solr 9.3 with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, solr, solrj

I am trying Solr v9.3 to test their capabilities. I have created a test application with Spring Boot v3.1.1, and included a small test where I am using a `EmbeddedSolrServer`.

No so much code, and is based on some examples I have found:

```
EmbeddedSolrServer solrClient = new EmbeddedSolrServer(solrHome, coreName);

// create a test document
SolrInputDocument document1 = new SolrInputDocument();
document1.addField("id", "1");
SolrInputDocument document2 = new SolrInputDocument();
document2.addField("id", "2");
solrClient.add(Arrays.asList(document1, document2));
```

The problem is that when executing, I get a:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Application

at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.<init>(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:98)
...
```

Usually, the solution for this bug, is to add some dependencies, such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

But now, I get a:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/ws/rs/core/Configurable

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.<init>(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:98)
...
```

Probably that means that Solr is not prepared for using `jakarta` packages, and therefore is not compatible with Sprint Boot 3.X. Does somebody has success in using Solr EmbeddedSolrServer in Spring Booty 3.X? Or it is know that is not compatible (yet)?

Comment: From the [Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide) "Support for Apache Solr has been removed as its Jetty-based client, Http2SolrClient, is not compatible with Jetty 11."

Comment: I understand that this is more related to the `spring-data-solr` package, that I am not using. But clearly they are addressing that they have faced some incompatibility issues that probably are affecting other Solr components. And I can imagine that the embedded server can have the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that Spring Boot 3 will not be compatible with Solr 9.3 due to the different Jetty versions.

We expect to ship Solr 10.0 based on Jetty 12 in late 2024 which should better align on the `jakarta` namespace.

Note that using EmbeddedSolrServer is not recommended and is an expert option for rare use cases. It will cause the entire `solr-core` application with all its dependencies to be running within your application's JVM and risk causing many more library conflicts.

A better option is to start Solr as a standalone server (e.g. through `bin/solr start` or through Docker `docker run -p 8983:8983 solr:9`), and then use SolrJ client to connect to the Solr server. You can then use SpringBoot 3 and the `HttpSolrClient` by excluding all `jetty` dependencies from your maven SolrJ import, to avoid javax/jakarta clash. Excluding jetty classes is safe since `HttpSolrClient` depends on a different http client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was following some examples that uses the EmbeddedSolrServer. I use it mainly for automated testing purposes, but in other systems as a standalone docker container as you suggest. Yes, this skip the issue. But what I like the most from your answer, is your confirmation that on Solr 10.0 will be more compatiable with Spring Boot 3.0